# class interactions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a plant breeding program, a bit sketchy so far, but this is my first object oriented programming...

```
import requests
import random

class environment:
    def __init__(self, weather = None, temperature = None, soil_type = None):
        self.weather = weather
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.soil_type = soil_type

    def get_weather(self):
        self.zip_code = input("Enter your zip code to get weather info: ")
        self.url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=a9fed4c32128f18e6142d3bd49fb5f7d&units=metric&zip=" + self.zip_code
        self.response = requests.get(self.url) 
        self.result = self.response.json()
        if self.result["cod"] != "404":
            self.weather = self.result['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
            self.temperature = self.result['list'][0]['main']['temp']

            print("Weather: {}".format(self.result['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']))
            if "rain" in self.weather.lower() and "drizzle" not in self.weather.lower():
                print("You need to think about adjusting watering amount.")
            elif "drizzle" in self.weather.lower():
                print("You need to think about adjusting watering amount, but not much adjustment.")
            elif "clouds" in self.weather.lower():
                print("Moderate sunshine.")
            elif "clear sky" in self.weather.lower():
                print("Sunshine, sunshine, sunshine...")

            print("Temperature: {} °C".format(self.result['list'][0]['main']['temp']))
            if self.temperature >= 35:
                print("Temperature is high.")
            elif 35 > self.temperature >= 10:
                print("Temperature is moderate.")
            elif 10 > self.temperature >= 0:
                print("Temperature is low.")
            else:
                print("Too low for the plant to survive.")

        else:
            print("Zip code not found.")

    def choose_soil_type(self):
        self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type among these - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")

class plants:
    def __init__(self, preferred_sunshine = None, preferred_water = None, preferred_fertilizer = None, preferred_temp = None, preferred_soil = None):
        self.preferred_sunshine = preferred_sunshine
        self.preferred_water = preferred_water
        self.preferred_fertilizer = preferred_fertilizer
        self.preferred_temp = preferred_temp
        self.preferred_soil = preferred_soil

    def choose_plant(self):
        self.choose = input("Please choose your plant to breed: ")
        if self.choose == "lemon":
            self.preferred_sunshine = 9
            self.preferred_water = 5
            self.preferred_fertilizer = 3
            self.preferred_temp = "high"
            self.preferred_soil = "neutral"
        elif self.choose == "blueberry":
            self.preferred_sunshine = 6
            self.preferred_water = 8
            self.preferred_fertilizer = 5
            self.preferred_temp = "moderate"
            self.preferred_soil = "acidic"
        elif self.choose == "pear":
            self.preferred_sunshine = 3
            self.preferred_water = 3
            self.preferred_fertilizer = 7
            self.preferred_temp = "low"
            self.preferred_soil = "alkaline"
        else:
            print("not a valid plant")

class treatment:
    def __init__(self, water = 0, fertilizer = 0, weed = True):
        self.water = water
        self.fertilizer = fertilizer
        self.weed = weed

    def provide_water(self):
        self.water = input("Please enter the amount of water: ")
        if self.water == self.preferred_water:
            self.water_score = 10
        elif preferred_water - 2 <= self.water <= self.preferred_water + 2:
            self.water_score = 7
        else:
            self.water_score = 4        
        return self.water_score

    def provide_fertilizer(self):
        self.fertilizer = input("Please enter the amount of fertilizer: ")
        if self.fertilizer == self.preferred_fertilizer:
            self.fertilizer_score = 10
        elif preferred_fertilizer - 2 <= self.water <= self.preferred_fertilizer + 2:
            self.fertilizer_score = 7
        else:
            self.fertilizer_score = 4  

    def remove_weed(self):
        count = 0
        while self.weed == True:
            x = 1* random.random()
            count += 1
            if x < 0.3:
                self.weed == False
                print("You have removed the weeds", count, "times to help the plant grow. Good job!")
                break
        if count <= 3:
            self.weed_score = 10
        else:
            self.weed_score = 5





a = environment()
a.get_weather()
a.choose_soil_type()
b = plants()
b.choose_plant()
c = treatment()
c.provide_water()
```

I'm wondering how to interact between classes...

```
Enter your zip code to get weather info: 94560
Weather: light rain
You need to think about adjusting watering amount.
Temperature: 8.05 °C
Temperature is low.
Please choose soil type among these - alkaline, neutral, acidic: acidic
Please choose your plant to breed: lemon
Please enter the amount of water: 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-50fbdf0f3aa5> in <module>
    123 b.choose_plant()
    124 c = treatment()
--> 125 c.provide_water()

<ipython-input-88-50fbdf0f3aa5> in provide_water(self)
     82     def provide_water(self):
     83         self.water = input("Please enter the amount of water: ")
---> 84         if self.water == self.preferred_water:
     85             self.water_score = 10
     86         elif preferred_water - 2 <= self.water <= self.preferred_water + 2:

AttributeError: 'treatment' object has no attribute 'preferred_water'
```

This program creates an error like above... I know preferred_water is not in the treatment object, but I would like to get the information from class "plants" based on my choice from the "choose_plant" function...

Also I would like to adjust the treatment amount based on the weather. But right now my classes act independently haha... How should I start from? :) any comment would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, the `treatment` and `plant` instances are independent of one another. There is no way of accessing `plant` data, inside the `treatment` instance. What you would want, is that the treatment is related, so that a `treatment` instance can view and use the `plant` instance.

So, inside your `treatment` you want to add something like this:

```
class treatment:
    def __init__(self, plant, water = 0, fertilizer = 0, weed = True):
        self.water = water
        self.fertilizer = fertilizer
        self.weed = weed
        self.plant = plant
```

This means, that when a `treatment` object is created, it requires a `plant` object, to which the `treatment` will be related.

And then you're going to want to create a treatment instance like this,:

```
b = plants()
c = treatment(b) # create treatment, while passing along the plant instance.
```

Then in the `provide_water` function, you can access the `plant` instance.

```
def provide_water(self):
        self.water = input("Please enter the amount of water: ")
        if self.water == self.plant.preferred_water:
            self.water_score = 10
```